# Product of simple modules not semi-simple

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence, semi-simple-rings

Consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M := \prod_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. I'm looking for an exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules
$$0 \rightarrow L \rightarrow M \rightarrow N \rightarrow 0
$$
that doesn't split. I've tried a few but every time I think I have one it turns out I did something wrong. I'm starting to doubt whether $M$ really is semi-simple.

Comment: I’m not sure what you intended by “the R module”. What do you think the action is for an arbitrary $R$?

Comment: What ring is $R$?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I’ll correct it

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: No, it doesn't. What is $R$, and what is the $R$-module structure on $M$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such example: $\prod_\mathbb{N}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is in fact a semisimple $\mathbb{Z}$-module.  Indeed, since it is a $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$-vector space, it can be written as a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, so as a direct sum of simple modules it is semisimple.

Comment: Is this general? i.e. is every product of simple modules semi-simple?

Comment: No, it's not true more generally.

Comment: Could you give me a hint for finding one which isn't (semi-simple)?

Comment: Well, this example failed because the product was still a vector space over $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.  How could you take a product of simple $\mathbb{Z}$-modules that wouldn't be a vector space over any field (or more generally, a module over any semisimple quotient of $\mathbb{Z}$)?